# Product rule for bilinear maps between Euclidean spaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, bilinear-form

Consider

- a bilinear map $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle : \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$,
- an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^j$,
- a pair of maps $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g: U \to \mathbb R^n$, and
- the composite map $F(x) = \langle f(x), g(x) \rangle$.

Then, is it necessarily true that
$$
dF_{a}(b) = \langle df_{a}(b), g(a) \rangle + \langle f(a), dg_{a}(b) \rangle,
$$
and if not, is there a similar product rule for $dF$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the equality

$$
dF_{a}(b) = \langle df_{a}(b), g(a) \rangle + \langle f(a), dg_{a}(b) \rangle,
$$ always holds. This is a consequence of the chain rule as the derivative of the map $G(u,v) = \langle u, v \rangle$ is

$$G^\prime(u,v)(h,k) = \langle u, k \rangle + \langle h, v \rangle.$$